# Boto3 create glue triggers with different types in one workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

Can anyone please guide me steps to create multiple triggers types one with conditional and other with scheduled trigger type in single workflow

So far I have used create_trigger function . But above requirement not sure how to address.

Can any one help here please.

I have tried with below syntax didn't work

```py
response = client.create_trigger(
    Name='two_triggers',
    WorkflowName='wf_With_two_tirggers',
    Type='SCHEDULED',
    Schedule='cron(0 12 * * ? *)',
    Actions=[
        {   
            'JobName': 'abc_dev',
            'Arguments': {
                'string': 'string'
            },
            'Timeout': 123,
            'SecurityConfiguration': 'string',
            'NotificationProperty': {
                'NotifyDelayAfter': 123
            },
            'Trigger': 'string'
        },
    ],
    Type='CONDITIONAL',
    Predicate={
        'Logical': 'ANY',
        'Conditions': [
            {
                'LogicalOperator': 'EQUALS',
                'JobName': 'def_dev',
                'State': 'SUCCEEDED'
            },
        ]
    },
    Actions=[
        {
            'JobName': 'ghi_dev',
            'Arguments': {
                'string': 'string'
            },
            'Timeout': 123,
            'SecurityConfiguration': 'string',
            'NotificationProperty': {
                'NotifyDelayAfter': 123
            },
            'CrawlerName': 'string'
        },
    ],
    Description='string',
    StartOnCreation=True,
    Tags={
        'string': 'string'
    }
)
```

Below is the design workflow struggling to write code for. Tried with above code for below design using boto3 didn't work

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and explain what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I have updated my post with sample code and design .

Comment: When you say "didn't work", please add any error messages and explain what the expected vs. actual behavior is.

Comment: With above code given it is throwing me below error.


SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated (<stdin>, line 20).

My Expectation is workflow has to be created in (UI:aws glue->workflow).  when I execute the code snippet mentioned.  And when I open and see the workflow there should be two triggers one with SCHEDULED TRIGGER and CONDITIONAL TRIGGER  as mentioned in design. Exactly that is how output should look like

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information. If you're getting syntax errors, it's time to check the [docs for the create_client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_trigger) API and make sure that your code follows the structure that the SDK expects.

Comment: Hi Maurice, In no SDK docs the syntax is mentioned about adding dual triggers in one workflow  . If you could produce any solution of my requirement please post it it

Answer (score 1):

Yes I figured out on an answer. Below is the code for design given in question

```
import boto3
import os
import logging
glue = boto3.client(service_name="glue", region_name='us-east-1')


response = glue.create_workflow(
    Name="dual_trigger_wf")

response1 = glue.create_trigger(
    Name="trigger_one_to_many",
    WorkflowName="dual_trigger_wf",
    Type="SCHEDULED",
    Schedule="cron(0 8 * * ? *)",
    Actions=[
        {
            "JobName": "abc",
            "Arguments": {"string": "string"},
            "Timeout": 123,
            "SecurityConfiguration": "string",
            "NotificationProperty": {"NotifyDelayAfter": 123},
        },
        {
            "JobName": "def",
            "Arguments": {"string": "string"},
            "Timeout": 123,
            "SecurityConfiguration": "string",
            "NotificationProperty": {"NotifyDelayAfter": 123},
        },
    ],
    Description="string",
    StartOnCreation=False,
)


response2 = glue.create_trigger(
    Name="trigger_many_to_one",
    WorkflowName="dual_trigger_wf",
    Type="CONDITIONAL",
    Predicate={
        "Logical": "AND",
        "Conditions": [
            {
                "LogicalOperator": "EQUALS",
                "JobName": "abc",
                "State": "SUCCEEDED",
            },
            {
                "LogicalOperator": "EQUALS",
                "JobName": "def",
                "State": "SUCCEEDED",
            },
        ],
    },
    Actions=[
        {
            "JobName": "ghi",
            "Arguments": {"string": "string"},
            "Timeout": 123,
            "SecurityConfiguration": "string",
            "NotificationProperty": {"NotifyDelayAfter": 123},
        }
    ],
    Description="string",
    StartOnCreation=False,
)
```